# What types of visa status in the UK render one liable for VAT?

Tags: visas, uk, bookings, taxes, tax-refunds

And what types of statuses are exempt from it?

I had a consultation with an immigration lawyer and asked about VAT in their rates and they said that since I'd never been in the UK on anything other than a visitor status, I would not have to pay VAT.

How can I replicate and invoke this with other transactions?

Comment: Do you mean what visa statuses allow you to not pay (or to reclaim) VAT on purchases?

Comment: Note that whatever happens, VAT must be paid first, and will only be reimbursed (less handling fees etc.) once the buyer has left the EU customs territory. Also, it only applies to goods, any services rendered, as well as any food or beverage consumed, will be liable to VAT which cannot be reimbursed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no exemption from VAT based on visa type. There is a VAT refund scheme based on where you live or where you plan to live for the next 12 months. I am a British Citizen, so no visa, but can use the scheme because I live in California and can prove it.

I recommend reading the whole of [Claim VAT back on tax-free shopping in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/claim-vat-back-on-tax-free-shopping-in-the-uk-notice-7041).

[3. Who can use the scheme](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/claim-vat-back-on-tax-free-shopping-in-the-uk-notice-7041#section3) has the conditions. You either need to live outside the UK or EU, or plan to do so for the next 12 months. You must export the goods "by the last day of the third month after the the month you bought them in".

Comment: I think this maybe wrong. (see DJClayworth's answer below.)

Comment: @JosephP. Could you be specific about what you think is incorrect? I based this answer on a combination of my practical experience of tax-free shopping in the UK and a gov.uk web page to which I link.

Comment: @JosephP. I don't see anything in DJClayworth's answer that contradicts this answer.

Comment: Well, in my view "being a visitor" constitutes a certain type of immigration status, as it precludes some others...

Comment: @JosephP. As noted above, I am a British Citizen. There is no immigration status information that would say I am not a UK resident. You have to look past visas etc. to the question "Where do you live?". In my case, I spend over 90% of my time in the US.

Comment: I see. What I had understood from the solicitor was that it was kinked to not having ever possessed any status other than a visitors visa or the equivalent, on which point she was quite equivocal. But your understanding seems to accord more with my direct observations in society...

Answer (score 2):

In order to purchase goods in the UK without paying VAT [there are two main criteria](https://www.gov.uk/tax-on-shopping/taxfree-shopping):

1. You must be  visitor to the UK
2. The goods must be exported unused.

No mention is explicitly made of visa categories. Obviously residential visas are not included. If you were leaving the UK with no plans to return after a short stay you might reasonably be counted as a visitor. I would expect that the second criterion would be much more restrictive.

Note that VAT refunds can be claimed even by residents if they are leaving the EU for at least 12 months.

Comment: Are you sure about the "unused" rule? I bought some warm clothing on a trip to London, and had no problem claiming the VAT back on clothes I had worn.

Comment: I saw the comment about "goods you’ve already used in the UK or EU, such as perfume", but I think that is just reiterating that you must export the complete item. No claiming a full bottle of perfume and only showing half a bottle.

Comment: You may be right. I'm going to defer to your better-referenced answer.

Comment: I had a consultation with an immigration lawyer and asked about VAT in their rates and they said that since I'd never been in the UK on anything other than a visitor status, I would not have to pay VAT.

Comment: So what was this about, and how can I achieve the same thing with other transactions?

Comment: Were you in the UK for the consultation?

Comment: The reason for my question about your location is that it may have been a case of exported services, if you were outside the UK.